# React Native: navigation.setOptions not working when call navigation.replace

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, stack-navigator

Currently, I have a screen that show the record detail and also `Previous` and `Next` buttons to navigate among different records. I use `CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS` as default screen options so the animation is sliding horizontally to left direction when entering the new screen.

For `Next` button, I could use `navigation.replace` normally and the animation work perfectly fine.

```
const showNextSample = () => {
    let currentIndex = itemIdList.indexOf(currentId);
    let nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % itemIdList.length;
    let nextId = itemIdList[nextIndex];
    navigation.replace('DataEntry', { ...route.params, sampleid: nextId });
}
```

For `Previous` button, I want to reverse the animation direction so I tried setting `gestureDirection`. However, the direction when changing the screen is still the same (Other feature and record detail are still working correctly).

```
const showPrevSample = () => {
    let currentIndex = itemIdList.indexOf(currentId);
    let prevIndex = currentIndex ? currentIndex - 1 : itemIdList.length - 1;
    let prevId = itemIdList[prevIndex];
    navigation.setOptions({ gestureDirection: 'horizontal-inverted' });
    navigation.replace('DataEntry', { ...route.params, sampleid: prevId }); //Animation Direction is still the same
}
```

Comment: same here, works when setting gesture direction at root, but not in component